# Is there a way to connect a QSlider and a QLineEdit object to each other?

Tags: c++, qt, slider, signals-slots, qlineedit

I'm trying to connect a Slider and LineEdit widget together so that when one is changed the other will match this value.

I'm struggling since lineEdit takes strings and Slider takes ints. I already used setValidator on the lineEdit so that only ints can be entered.

I tried using the old signals and slots syntax with no luck using a couple different methods from a quick Google search.

```
connect(textbox, SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)),slider,
        SLOT((QString)));
```

Should I be using a different widget entirely than LineEdit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`lineEdit()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#lineEdit) method of [`QSpinBox()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html):

```cpp
connect(textbox, &QLineEdit::textEdited, slider->lineEdit(), &QLineEdit::setText);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using stackoverflow firsty to answer others' question,Hahaha.

1. The better binding signal for QSlider is **QSlider::sliderMoved**, and do not bingding **QSlider::valueChanged**, otherwise they will conflict, maybe you can try it.
2. Binding **QLineEdit::textChanged** signal for QLineEdit.

code here:

```
connect(ui->horizontalSlider,&QSlider::sliderMoved,this,[=]{
    int val=ui->horizontalSlider->value();
    //You can process the variable val here.....
    ui->lineEdit->setText(QString::number(val));
});

connect(ui->lineEdit,&QLineEdit::textChanged,this,[=]{
    int val=ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();
    //You can process the variable val here.....
    ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(val);
});
```